# .NET webbrowser & textarea

Tags: c#, vb.net, browser

I want to write data within the Webbrowser control in VB.NET/C# .

This the page code : `<textarea id="paste_content" name="paste_content"></textarea>`

I have tried so far : `WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("paste_content").SetAttribute("Value", "test")`

But it doesn't work ...

Answer (score 1):

I write an example:(try this(in C#))

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<html><body><textarea id=\"paste_content\" name=\"paste_content\"></textarea></body></html>";
        }

        void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("paste_content").InnerText = "test";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use htmlelement for this purpose

```
HtmlElement textArea = webBrowser1.Document.All["paste_content"];
if (textArea != null)
{
  textArea.InnerText = "This is a test";
}
```

Comment: I have converted it to VB.NET and applied it under documentcompleted event , but it didn't work .... This is the site btw : http://privatepaste.com/