# Get (altered) textarea content from webBrowser element in C#

Tags: c#, windows, forms, tinymce, textarea

I've searched the web for 2 days now and am about to give up on this, but I'm soo close to the final solution... so you're my last hope. ;)

I have made a little C# application with Windows Forms GUI that uses a webBrowser element to display an HTML file with a TinyMCE editor embedded - this way I get a nice window with customizable editor functions I can use perfectly for my needs in this project.
I can set the textarea input for this editor window without problems thanks to this solution posted here on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16322324/3498545

However I'm having big troubles reading text from this textarea. If I read the element by ID as shown (for setting content) in the solution above, I get the old text, as TinyMCE never really saves the changes.
But how do I get the input that my users will make in the textarea via TinyMCE? Is there some way to trigger a form send in HTML to get this input?

Thank you so much for you help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to answer my own question (maybe others find this useful sometime later):

The changes of TinyMCE don't get written back to the textarea field in realtime, so I had to work around that. One solution would be to add something in the javascript header that writes every change back to the textarea immediately, however this caused problems for me as TinyMCE code clean up is not involved at this point.
My solution was to temporarily create a new file where the input of the TinyMCE field gets written directly into source code, which is a piece of cake to read back in C#.

The javascript code needed looks like this:

```
setup : function(editor){
  editor.on('submit', function (){
    tinymce.triggerSave();
    document.writeln("<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><div id='content'>"+document.getElementById('textarea').value+"</div></body></html>")
    document.close()
  });
}
```

After that you can read the content in C# with the following code:

```
webBrowser.Document.GetElementById("content").InnerHtml
```

Now I can store HTML formatted code in my SQL database that can be managed and edited with a shiny interface. ;)